# How to style a title with a parallelogram background?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

[image]

I need to style my web page title like this image, Please could you help with this.

Comment: i think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798793/draw-angular-side-parallelogram-using-css) can help you

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680557/parallelogram-shape-in-css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parallelogram shape in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680557/parallelogram-shape-in-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is it

Adjust it to your needs

```css
#parallelogram {
  padding: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: darkred;
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
  }
#text {
  transform: initial;
  color: white;
  transform: skewX(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="parallelogram">
  <div id="text">
    Coding practice
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .title {
        background: linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 50%, #yourColor 50%);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        transform: skewX(-20deg);
}